# List all available ResourceBundle Files 

Tags: java, plugins, resourcebundle

i am using ResourceBundle and I want to give the user an option to select a language for the GUI.

i want to get a list of all resource files that are under a specific package.

i don't know what resources I will have since this application is based on plug-ins.

Is there an option to ask from java to search all available resources under a package?

(if no i guess the plug-in should give all available local for it)

thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files may reside on a web server. There is no standard way of listing files (pages) on a web server. So, in general, what you need to do is remember which locales you have resources for (perhaps create a list as part of your build process).